# 2 errors in android XML unbound xml & root not well formed

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, admob, adview

So earlier it said i had junk xml now after playing around and trying different solutions i have 2 errors instead of 1! Now i have an error next to 
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> that says:error parsing prefix: unbound XML

and the other error next to com.admob.android.ads.AdView says:The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?<
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

/>

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/ad" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:backgroundColor="#000000"
  xmlns:primaryTextColor="FFFFFF"
  xmlns:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a container.  Right click on your `WebView` in Eclipses "Outline" window and choose "Wrap in container"

If you're not using Eclipse, just put the Webview and the AdView within a Layout widget

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView xmlns:backgroundColor="#000000"
        xmlns:primaryTextColor="FFFFFF"
        xmlns:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is embarrassing but how do i do that? I assume the outline container is either the pane on the left(unless that is the package explorer) or the main center area where i can see the XML.

Comment: In Eclipse's menu bar, go to Window > Show Views.  If it's not in the list then choose Other and type in Outline

Comment: Oh i see i completely skipped the layout, Duh! But im still getting an error parsing XML:unbound prefix next to <com.admob.android.ads.AdView

Comment: Is the AdMob library imported to the project?

Comment: if you mean the java file yes. I copied the AdMobSDK in to the libs folder and then added it.

Comment: it says unbound prefix so something must be wrong here:<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/ad" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:backgroundColor="#000000"
      xmlns:primaryTextColor="FFFFFF"
      xmlns:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
      />             sorry for the crappy layout

Answer (score 1):

`<?xml` must be the first characters in an XML file.

Remove your leading whitespace.

Comment: There is no whitespace right above <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> Thats literally the first line of the document